# String Replace in Lua

Tags: lua, replace

i am looking to write a function in Lua that replaces all occurrences of one string with another, e.g.:

```
function string.replace(s, oldValue, newValue)
   return string.gsub(s, oldValue, newValue);
end;
```

What i need (unless Lua already has a string replace function) is a function to escape Lua <strike>regular expression</strike>pattern strings (unless Lua already has an Escape<strike>RegularExpression</strike>Pattern function)

i've tried to start writing the proper `string.replace` function:

```
local function EscapeRegularExpression(pattern)
    -- "." ==> "%."
    local s = string.gsub(pattern, "%." "%%%.");

    return s;
end;

function string.replace(s, oldValue, newValue)
    oldValue = EscapeRegularExpression(oldValue);
    newValue = EscapeRegularExpression(newValue);

    return string.gsub(s, oldValue, newValue);
end;
```

But i cannot easily think of all the Lua <strike>regular expression</strike>pattern keywords that need to be escaped.

### Bonus Example

Another example that needs a fix might be:

```
//Remove any locale thousands separator:
s = string.gsub(s, Locale.Thousand, "");

//Replace any locale decimal marks with a period
s = string.gsub(s, Locale.Decimal, "%.");
```

Comment: Lua does not have regular expressions. It has *patterns*. They're similar, but not as powerful as actual regexes.

Comment: Lua patterns make me think that someone got a description of regular expressions in a noisy bar one night and the next day, after they'd sobered up, implemented what they could remember.  They are exactly enough like normal regular expressions to trap the unwary and no more. </rant>

Comment: @Perry You didn't pass W3C test because you forgot the opening tag!

Comment: @HakanBoztepe In html, some elements are *forbidden* from having a closing tag (e.g. `IMG`). And i think in html the `rant` element is forbidden from having an opening tag.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
-- Inhibit Regular Expression magic characters ^$()%.[]*+-?)
function strPlainText(strText)
    -- Prefix every non-alphanumeric character (%W) with a % escape character, 
    -- where %% is the % escape, and %1 is original character
    return strText:gsub("(%W)","%%%1")
end -- function strPlainText
```

Comment: This will also change '/' to '%/' which is not in your magic char set

Answer (score 1):

Check out documentation on patterns (that's [section 5.4.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) for Lua 5.1), most interesting would be list of magic characters:

> x: (where x is not one of the magic characters ^$()%.[]*+-?)
>   represents the character x itself.

Escape them with preceding `%` before using string in `gsub` and you're done.

To be extra sure you can set up a `while` loop with `string.find` that have convenient "plain" flag and `string.sub` necessary parts of string manually.